# Get values from <ui:repeat> separately

Tags: java, user-interface, repeater, uirepeat

I am using Prime-faces to create drop downs in `<ui:repeat>` tag. I'm trying to get values of each drop down separately.

The code I have tried:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{deviceTypeController.lstSensors}" var="sensor">
     <p:selectOneMenu value="#{deviceTypeController.selectedSensorBean}">
         <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One"/>
         <f:selectItems value="#{deviceTypeController.lstSensors}" var="fields"
                        itemLabel="#{fields.sensor}" itemValue="#{fields}"/>
     </p:selectOneMenu>
</ui:repeat>
```

I have some strings in this list `#{deviceTypeController.lstSensors}`.

`<ui:repeat>` showing all those drop downs[In the List]

But how can I get each value from them?

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could additional parameter, lets say the parameter name is sensor_name and this value could be extracted from the method, selectedSensorBean. You also need an identifer in your sensor variable, ex: #{sensor.name}

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{deviceTypeController.selectedSensorBean}">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One"/>
     <f:param name="sensor_name" value="#{sensor.name}" /> 
     <f:selectItems value="#{deviceTypeController.lstSensors}" var="fields"
                    itemLabel="#{fields.sensor}" itemValue="#{fields}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```